# How to choose Strategy in SimpleImputer

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

How to choose strategy ( mean, median, most_frequent, constant) in a SimpleImputer?
What exactly "constant" strategy does ?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to this [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) which contains complete description for each strategy.

`constant` strategy would fill the missing values with a constant which will be defined by the parameter `fill_value`.

Example:

```
imp_constant = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value = 1)
imp_constant.fit_transform([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9]])
```

Orignal:

```
([[ 7.,  2.,  3.],
 [ 4., nan,  6.],
 [10.,  5.,  9.]])
```

Output:

```
([[ 7.,  2.,  3.],
  [ 4.,  1.,  6.],
  [10.,  5.,  9.]])
```

In the above example since I've chosen `strategy='constant'`, therefore I need to define the constant value which needs to filled that is done using the parameter `fill_value = 1`. `NaN` occurrence would then be filled by `1`.